# How do I sort and display by a matrix date field?

Tags: matrix, datetime

I have an entries in a section called 'garden', with a matrix field called 'sowing' - this matrix has a block called 'locationDate' and two fields 'sowingDate' and 'sowingLocation'.

I want to loop through and show the last 5 things sown in the garden, so based on other examples and using low blocks, I have this code:

```
{% set allSown = craft.lowblocks.blocks.fieldId(12).type("locationDate").order("sowingDate").limit(5) %}
{% set entryIds = [] %}

{% for sown in allSown %}
    {% set entry = sown.title %}
    {% set entryIds = entryIds | merge([entry.id]) %}
{% endfor %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.section("garden").id(entryIds).fixedOrder(true).status("live,pending") %}

{% for sown in entries %}
    {{ sown.title }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

So my question is, why can't I view the entries, and what do I need to do to display the date of the matrix field? It seems like it should working, but I am missing something for sure.

** note I need to have a matix date there as there are often multiple sowing locations and dates per entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not worked with Lowblocks yet, but it looks like it returns an array of Matrix block models. To get to the related entries you need to access the `owner` property.

```
{% set entryIds = [] %}
{% for sown in allSown %}
    {% set blockId = sown.id %}
    {% set entryIds = entryIds|merge([blockId.owner.id]) %}
{% endfor %}
```

But do you really need those entry IDs? You could just display the blocks?

```
{% for sown in allSown %}
    {{ sown.owner.title }}
    {{ sown.sowingLocation }}
    {{ sown.sowingDate }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: hmm tried that but I am getting this: Object of class Craft\ElementCriteriaModel could not be converted to string

/home/aaronjay/craft/templates/index.html(-1)

Comment: What gives you this error? The line you print owner.title?

Comment: nah the date - {{ sown.sowingDate|date("d - M") }}  this resolved it when I take the {{ sown.sowingLocation }} out.